# SSH to amazon instance times out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-ami

Tried Amazon AMI and Linux AMI

Yup, set up my security groups with anywhere port 22

what else can i try?  the log for the instance looks ok, like it started up and it's running.  the status checks are 2/2

what else can i try?
cheers

Comment: I have not use VPC, only AWS classic.  I found some docs that state I need to check the route table for the subnet and add a route that sends all traffic destined outside the VPC to the Internet gateway for the VPC.  I have no idea what this means.

Comment: another document also states to check the network ACL for the subnet.  it must allow inbound and outbound traffic from your public IP.  again, not sure where to find this in the amazon console.

Comment: did you apply the key pair when create a new instance?

Comment: yup, definitely applied the keypair.  Even so, I think that would be a different error.  When I ssh, it just times out.  I thought maybe it was U-Verse, but I tried from a different provider and same results.  Definitely seems like port 22 is not open on the server, even though I have a security group for it.

ssh -i “xxx.pem" ec2-user@52.2.101.222

ssh: connect to host 52.2.101.222 port 22: Operation timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, i had a bad subnet.  When i launched a new instance and picked a different subnet, I was then able to SSH.  (I never modified the default subnets that came with my account).